# Got error at iReport 5.6 on opening JRXML: "Attribute 'hTextAlign' is not allowed to appear in element 'style'"

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Has anyone ever gotten this error in *iReport 5.6* when trying to open the *jrxml* file?

> Attribute 'hTextAlign' is not allowed to appear in element 'style'

Comment: Looks like you are trying to open not supported *jrxml* (6.x version)

Comment: Thank you. It was the version, as it was done in iReport, but was edited in Jasper Studio 6.2 and added features that iReport does not support.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The cause of problem

The *jrxml* file is just a *xml* file. It is a common practice to validate *xml* files with help of [*XSD* schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)).

The *JasperReports* engine is doing the same - it is using *xsd* schema to validate the report's template (*jrxml* file).

The *xsd* was changed at *6.x* version compared with *5.x* version.

The schema for latest version of *JasperReports* is available with [*url*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd). You can always find the link to schema at header of *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ... xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" ...>
```

Looks like your template (*jrxml* file) was created or edited with *JasperReports Studio* of *6.x* version and saved without applying compatitbility with *5.x version* option (*Compatibility warning dialog*).

#### How to solve this issue:

1. You can use *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JSS*) for modifying report's template. Maybe it is the best choice because the *iReport* is **deprecated** (it is not supported since the end of 2015 year) and supports only *5.6 and oldest versions* of *JasperReports* templates/features.
2. You can save the template at compatitbility mode as *5.x* version at *JSS* and after this continue edit the *jrxml* file with *iReport*

The dialog appears during saving template at *JSS* and looks like this:

[image: Dialog at JSS]

To enable this dialog you should change settings at form called via *Window -> Preferences* menu.

[image: Preferences at JSS]

3. Always use only *iReport* designer. But be aware: **it does not support *6+* version of *JasperReports* templates.**

#### How to check the difference in schemas of *5.x* and *6.x* versions

The *xsd* schema for any version of *JasperReports* can be found at *JasperReports package with source code* or at repository of source code.

This is a fragment (screenshot) of comparing *xsd* files of *5.6.1* (left panel) and *6.3.0* (right panel) versions.

[image: Diff of two xsd]

As you can see that the `hTextAlign` attribute from your error message presents only at *xsd* of *6.x* version. This is a cause of the error you got

Comment: Thank you! Switched to correct compatible version of Jasper Studio.

Comment: switching to a compatible version as shown in image 2 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove all attribute **textAdjust="StretchHeight"** in textField tag. I have removed the attribute and it worked fine for me [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46kjj.png).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to parse an XML document. It worked after removing the `textAdjust` property from the report source XML. All values gives exception: CutText, StretchHeight and ScaleFont.

Answer (score 0):

Use **isStretchWithOverflow="true"** instead of **textAdjust="StretchHeight"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).