# Rotation of Text in Crosstab in Jasper Reports 4.5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab, text-rotation

For reasons too complicated to go into, I have to deploy a new report onto an existing JasperReports Server 4.5.0 installation.  It cannot be upgraded.  I figured that it would be easiest to use iReport 4.5.0 to ensure compatibility with the Server.  Am I mistaken?  Would it be better to use a newer version, or to switch to Jaspersoft Studio, or something else?

The report involves a crosstab with many columns.  In order to get them all to fit on one standard landscape page, I need to change the rotation of the column headers to vertical.  The data inside the cells themselves is very short.  I couldn't find an option in iReport to change the rotation of the text in the header, so I changed the XML from:

```
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ACTION_DESC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
```

To:

```
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30"/>
                            <textElement rotation="Left"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ACTION_DESC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
```

(In case you don't see it, I added a `rotation="Left"` to the `textElement`.)

It doesn't seem to have any effect on the preview, whether I'm previewing to HTML or PDF.  I have seen others referring to text rotation in versions even older than mine, so I didn't think that it's unsupported in 4.5.0.  Again, am I mistaken?

Comment: `Would it be better to use a newer version, or to switch to Jaspersoft Studio, or something else?` - You can use JSS and save report at compatability mode

Comment: `I have seen others referring to text rotation in versions even older than mine, so I didn't think that it's unsupported in 4.5.0. Again, am I mistaken?` - Did you try to do it not at crosstab, just one textField placed at Title, for example?

Comment: Rotation is working at crosstab, definitely. Last time I used a lot such textFields at JR 6.x

Comment: `It doesn't seem to have any effect on the preview, whether I'm previewing to HTML or PDF.` - Did you try to increase height of textField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to use *JaspersoftStudio* (*JSS*) instead of *iReport 4.5.0*?

Yes, for designing and testing templates locally. You can use compatibility mode to save template in format of *JasperReports 4.5.0* version.

But I'm not sure that the integration with old versions of *JasperReports Server* will be work ok at new versions of *JSS*.

#### Does crosstab support vertical rotated text (at header, for example)?

Yes, definitely. Rotation is supported by *textField* element, it is not the feature of crosstab.

The *iReport* has the ability to change rotation of text. You can find property ***Rotation*** at ***Text properties*** block.

[image: The property for changing text orientation]

The cause of issue you faced is that the size of *textField* is not enough for showing text. For example if we have *textField* with default horizontal text with its height too small for showing the text the rendered result will be empty.

You should just increase the height of *textField* to solve issue.

---

#### Notes

More details how to enable compatibility mode at *JSS* you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128032/876298) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110052/876298)